# Smarty foreach iteration in odd steps

Tags: php, foreach, smarty, iteration

My code:

```
    <div class="grid_3 {if $smarty.foreach.aussen.iteration ?????} alpha {/if}
{if $smarty.foreach.aussen.iteration % 4 == 0} omega {/if} "></div>
```

This works fine:

```
{if $smarty.foreach.aussen.iteration % 4 == 0} omega {/if}
```

But I need a formula for this steps 1, 5, 9, 13, 18, 23:

```
{if $smarty.foreach.aussen.iteration ?????} alpha {/if}
```

Comment: I didn't get why the inverse formula you're expecting 1, 5, 9, 13, 18 and 23... Shouldn't it be 1, 5, 9, 13, 17 and 21? Please, try to explain it more thoroughly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm just guessing here, since your question left some doubts... If I understood it correctly you're trying to achieve that:

```
    <div class="grid_3 {if $smarty.foreach.aussen.iteration % 4 == 1}alpha{/if}
{if $smarty.foreach.aussen.iteration % 4 == 0}omega{/if}"></div>
```

Comment: sorry for me bad english

Comment: @giller Well, `iteration % 4 == 0` will match on every iteration divisible by 4. On other hand, `iteration % 4 == 1` will match every time the remainder of division of iteration by 4 is 1, which means that it'll match every subsequent iteration of the prior formula. Did you got it? :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just 6 values you need special handing for (1, 5, 9, 13, 18, 23), then don't bother with creating a formula:

```
{foreach name = "aussen" from = $some_array}
  <div class="grid_3 {if $smarty.foreach.aussen.iteration|in_array:array(1, 5, 9, 13, 18, 23)} alpha {/if}
  {if $smarty.foreach.aussen.iteration % 4 == 0} omega {/if}"></div>
{/foreach}
```

Smarty 3, I'm not sure if this works in Smarty2, but even if it doesn't, with very small adjustments it should

Comment: |in_array:array(1, 5, 9, 13, 18, sorry dosnt work in smarty2 thats right